# Anyone knows where i could find the McMaster, H. C., “FAR 23 LOADS”, Aeroscience Software, 2.02 Edition?

Tags: aircraft-design, aircraft-physics, aircraft-structures

I am currently conducting research on wing lift distributions and came across the existence of a software tool called "FAR 23 LOADS," developed by McMaster, H. C. (Aeroscience Software, 2.02 Edition). This software seems to be specifically designed for analyzing  loads based on FAR 23 regulations.

However, despite my efforts, I have been unable to locate any sources providing access to this program. So far, I have only come across its user manual. I am genuinely intrigued by the capabilities of this software and would greatly appreciate any guidance on where or how I could gain access to it.

If any of you have information regarding the availability or any alternative software tools that can aid in analyzing wing lift distributions, I would be immensely grateful for your insights.

Thank you all in advance for your time and assistance.

Best regards,

Comment: You can request a quote [here](https://www.darcorp.com/far-23-loads-aeronautic-software/). For the history of the IP re-purchasing from McMaster, see [here](https://www.eng-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=211524).